# Input string was not in a correct format using MySQLDataAdapter

Tags: c#, mysql, string-formatting

I have looked at a number of the questions/answers here, but none of them seem to help

I have the below method to select data from a mySQL database

I have highlighted the line that the error happens on.

The string sql being passed is **SELECT * FROM tblDtCategory;**

OpenDbConnection(dbConn)) is to open the connection and return any problems with it, this runs fine

I can't understand why I'm getting this error, looking at the adapter everything seems ok, and I'm not trying to add or update to the database so it can't be a mismatched type...

```
    public DataTable Select(string sql)
    {            
        MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(DbConnection);

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();


        DataTable retTable = new DataTable();


        if (OpenDbConnection(dbConn))
        {
            try
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, dbConn);
                adapter.Fill(retTable); // error here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseDbConnection(dbConn);
            }
        }
        else
            return null;

        return retTable;
    }
```

image to show that it must have connected to the database

[image]

image to show what should be returned
[image]

**NOTE that the record: 3-newcat-1 was added from my app by changing the select statement to an insert statement - no problems (!)

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.ReadValue(MySqlPacket packet, Int64 length, Boolean nullVal)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue(Int32 index, Boolean checkNull)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at Downtime_Aquisition_Administrator.MySQLServer.Select(String sql) in d:\VS2012\Projects\Downtime Acquisition\Downtime Aquisition Administrator\Downtime Aquisition Administrator\frmMain.cs:line 1996
```

Comment: EDIT: this also happens when using a DataReader - when I hit the line `if(reader.Read())` or `while(reader.Read())`

Comment: are there any nulls in the db?

Comment: Can you add the table definition?  It looks like it is failing to convert a value for the result set.  Also do you have the latest version of MySql connector?  If you don't, try to see if upgrading fixes the problem.

Comment: @MEYWD what you see in the mySQL command line image is what there is in the database, there is nothing else

Comment: @DanielGimenez sorry what do you mean 'table definition'? as for the connector, as far as i know i do, there is no link for c#:[http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/), which would be best? -Edit- oh wait maybe the NET one :) -Edit2- already have the NET one, so I guess i have the most recent one installed, i will try reinstalling it

Comment: @iabbott Check what version of MySqlConnector you have.  I have 6.6.5 and I believe the latest version is 6.7.4.  When I say db definition, you can put your create table statement.

Comment: 6.7.4.    `command = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE tblDtCategory (CategoryID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, CategoryDescription VARCHAR(60), CategoryOrder INT, PRIMARY KEY(CategoryID));", dbConn);`

Comment: i have got past that error selecting on another table with no records, but whenever i try to add a record i can no longer select against that table:     `command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblDtCategory (CategoryDescription, CategoryOrder) VALUES (?, ?)", dbConn);

command.Parameters.Add("1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Machine";
command.Parameters.Add("2", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = 0;`

Comment: i also tried parameter 2 with type Int32, also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found the problem - school boy error lol

Went into the mySQL server and ran the setup again, but chose UTF-8 instead of one of the drop down options for the text format, now it works fine

..and I feel stupid :)